# PHP RegEx to read header comment data from file and add multiple matches to an array

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am building my own plugin system for adding new "Project Media Types" to my WordPress Projects Portfolio Plugin.

I am using the `WP_List_Table` WP Class to create a list of **Project Media Type Plugins** and allow manaing them by installling, activating, disabling, and deleting each of them.

[image]

My code scans a directory using PHP to detect valid **Project Media Type Plugins**

Each file it finds in this preset folder it then reads the header comment data of the file just like real WordPress plugins do to get information about the plugin.

Below is my function which scans the directory and reads the header comment data from each matching file into PHP variables when a match is detected...

```
    public function get_project_media_types_in_file_system ($from_folder = PLUGINS_FOLDER)
    {

        if ($handle = opendir($from_folder)) {

            while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
echo $file.'rrrrrrr<hr>';
                if (is_file($from_folder . $file)) {

                    if (strpos($from_folder . $file, '.php')) {
                        $fp = fopen($from_folder . $file, 'r');
                        // Pull only the first 8kiB of the file in.
                        $plugin_data = fread($fp, 8192);
                        fclose($fp);
                        preg_match('|Project Media Type Name:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $project_media_type_name);
                        preg_match('|Version:(.*)|i', $plugin_data, $version);
                        preg_match('|Description:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $description);
                        preg_match('|Admin Selector Image:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $admin_selector_image);
                        preg_match('|Screenshot Image 1:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $screenshot_image_1);
                        preg_match('|Screenshot Image 2:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $screenshot_image_2);
                        preg_match('|Author:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $author_name);
                        preg_match('|Author Email:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $author_email);
                        preg_match('|Author URI:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $author_uri);

                        foreach (array(
                                'project_media_type_name' ,
                                'version' ,
                                'description',
                                'admin_selector_image',
                                'screenshot_image_1',
                                'screenshot_image_2',
                                'author_name',
                                'author_email',
                                'author_uri'
                        ) as $field) {
                            if (! empty(${$field})){
                                ${$field} = trim(${$field}[1]);
                            }else{
                                ${$field} = '';
                            }
                        }

                        $project_media_type_plugin_data = array(
                            'file_name' => $file,
                            'project_media_type_name' => $project_media_type_name,
                            'class_name' => $project_media_type_name,
                            'title' => $project_media_type_name,
                            'description' => $description,
                            'version' => $version,
                            'admin_selector_image' => $admin_selector_image,
                            'screenshot_image_1' => $screenshot_image_1,
                            'screenshot_image_2' => $screenshot_image_2,
                            'author_name' => $author_name,
                            'author_email' => $author_email,
                            'author_uri' => $author_uri,
                            'installed' => 'no',
                            'active' => 0

                        );
                        $this->project_media_type_plugin_headers[] = $project_media_type_plugin_data;
                    }
                } else{
                    if ((is_dir($from_folder . $file)) && (substr($file,0,1) != '.')) {
                        $this->get_project_media_types_in_file_system($from_folder . $file . '/');
                    }
                }

            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
        return $this->project_media_type_plugin_headers;
    }
```

---

The line with this code:

```
preg_match('|Screenshot Image 1:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $screenshot_image_1);
```

is followed by another similar line with the number 1 changed to number 2.

My goal now is to modify this code to make it look for `Screenshot Image` instead of `Screenshot Image 1` or `Screenshot Image 2`

I want to be able to have any number of lines with `Screenshot Image` and have it add each matching line to an array so that a plugin can have as many images as they like.

---

Currently this is the format of a plugin header:

```
<?php
/**
 * Project Media Type Name: coverflow slider Test Plugin
 * Version: 2.0.0
 * Description: coverflow slider Test Plugin description
 * Admin Selector Image: https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/ApplicationFrameHost_2016-07-28_14-39-46.png
 * Screenshot Image 1: https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/Books-Animation.gif
 * Screenshot Image 2: https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/2013-05-20_23-11-40.png
 * Author: Jason Davis
 * Author Email: jason.davis.fl@gmail.com
 * Author URI: https://www.apollowebstudio.com
 */
```

With the new version it wouyld be able to look like this below and each image would be added to an array instead of a variable with a single string:

```
<?php
/**
 * Project Media Type Name: coverflow slider Test Plugin
 * Version: 2.0.0
 * Description: coverflow slider Test Plugin description
 * Admin Selector Image: https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/ApplicationFrameHost_2016-07-28_14-39-46.png
 * Screenshot Image: https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/Books-Animation.gif
 * Screenshot Image: https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/2013-05-20_23-11-40.png
 * Screenshot Image: https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/Books-Animation3.gif
 * Screenshot Image: https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2016/Books-Animation4.gif
 * Author: Jason Davis
 * Author Email: jason.davis.fl@gmail.com
 * Author URI: https://www.apollowebstudio.com
 */
```

---

Any help appreciated

Comment: lots to read but no question

Comment: Couldn't you just match for `Screenshot Image [123]` or `(\d+)` in that case? -- OT: is this plugin documentation scheme documented somewhere for WP? (looks like Drupal is sharing it even?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that with an easy regex like this:

```
preg_match('|Screenshot Image \d+:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $screenshot_image_1);
```

Bear in mind that $screenshot_image_1 will be overridden if you use it multiple times.

Maybe you should change it to **[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)** instead for this case which will store in an array all the matches.

```
preg_match_all('|Screenshot Image \d+:(.*)$|mi', $plugin_data, $screenshot_image_matches);
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT6kI0/2)**

**[IDE One demo](https://ideone.com/SKD2CF)**

Comment: I'm a bit confused as it appears this is what I am already doing to add each match to a single variable.  I am wanting to be able to match multiple matches into the same variable which is why it would need to save them as array items

Comment: @JasonDavis, I was updating my answer to mention that. Seems you need `preg_match_all`

Comment: Ok thanks!  As for the comment on `$` it is because I used this code from online and didn't write this part of it as I am not too good with RegEx stuff.  It essentially mimics what WordPress plugin system does though.  Would you be able to maybe show a demo for the `preg_match_all`?

Comment: Thank you.  I actually started playing with a demo of my own before I saw this however I got the same result as your IDE One Demo in which the array has 2 arrays  holding a set of matches.  The first set includes all the text and the 2nd array is more of what I need.  Just curious if you know why it creates the 2 arrays?  I will post my demo in a moment thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: @JasonDavis that's the way preg_match_all works, I put the documentation for you to learn about it.

Comment: @JasonDavis btw, did the answer help you to solve the question?

Comment: Yes it helped however I am still working through it to 100% completion.  It's almost working as needed dont worry I will select your answer =)